# Error: more than one library with package name 'com.github.xinthink.rnmk'

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

Building an app for Android with React-Native fails with this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.github.xinthink.rnmk'
```

This seems to be caused by react-native-material-kit (RNMK). but searching all the project files in Sublime Text, I couldn't find any duplication of 'com.github.xinthink.rnmk'. 
For reference, the iOS version of the app runs fine.

**Edit**

This is my **settings.gradle** file:

```
rootProject.name = 'myAppName'

include ':app'
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-material-kit'
project(':react-native-material-kit').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-material-kit/android')
include ':RNMaterialKit'
project(':RNMaterialKit').projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native-material-kit/android')
```

And these are the dependencies from **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-material-kit')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':RNMaterialKit')
}
```

When I comment out '*compile project(':RNMaterialKit')*' from the dependencies (the last line), The App builds and starts fine. However, doing so probably breaks react-native-material-kit, that uses that package.

Comment: can you share android/app/build.gradle file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry i can't put a comment yet. I think the problem is that you use more than one this library, in your `settings.gradle` and in your `build.gradle`.

So go to your `build.gradle` and delete `compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"`. Hope it 
works.

Comment: I can't find :app:processDebugResrouces in settings.gradle

Comment: could you please share your settings.gradle and your build.gradle

Comment: i think this is your problem : `compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"` try to delete it and see what you'll have !

Comment: Thanks! getting rid of compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" solved the problem.
Is it not required for anything else?

Comment: My pleasure... i update  my response, please mark it as accepted to help the others :). Happy Coding!

Comment: In fact i'm not sure if it not required for anything else. it depends to your needs. Good luck !

Comment: you mean delete the line 
`compile project(':react-native-material-kit')` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
from what I identified, the problem was I installed this package manually and then, it was added a second time with rnpm when using command :

```
rnpm link
```

I just ended up deleting one of the two entries, both in `settings.gradle` and `app/build.gradle` and that did the trick.